# Birchas Kohanim and Dreams

Tags: minhag, tefilla, kohen-priest, dream

By Birchas Kohanim there is a Tefila for people who had bad dreams. What does a Kohen do when he has a bad dream as he can not say the Tefila during Birchas Kohanim?

Comment: If it's a big issue, there's Taanis Chalom.  I've always seen these tefilos as tefilos you can say anytime, but have a stronger advantage at the time of Bircas Kohanim.  Not everyone can take advantage of every zechus.  Similar to every one can listen to krias hatorah, but not everyone gets an aliya.

Answer (score 5):

How about this? See [Orach Chaim siman 128, seif 25](http://books.google.com/books?id=5tIbPJZCAQ8C&lpg=PA25&ots=345vNrluTj&dq=congregation%20entirely%20of%20kohanim&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q&f=false), that where there is a shul consisting entirely of kohanim, and there are more than 10 in the minyan, those who are more than 10 go up to duchen.

So, have him assemble a bunch of his kohanim friends, let him stay as one of the 10 who don't duchen, and then he can say this tefillah.

Not that I endorse worrying so much about bad dreams.